# Does clearing Safari's cookies actually help the iPhone's overall performance?

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, performance

There's an iPhone 4 that has been getting pretty slow lately, so I figured I'd browse a bit about how to fix it. One particular tip several sites seem to suggest is clearing Safari's cookies.

I am skeptical about this, because, well, cookies are just files that are used when you browse the web. I suppose that clearing the cookies may speed up the *browsing* experience, but I don't see how can that speed up the overall iPhone performance. In fact, if I have Safari closed, I can't imagine any way in which cookies could affect my iPhone. I mean, it's not like the iPhone is checking my cookies when I am playing Angry Birds or something.

Is there any truth to this tip? Does it actually help iPhone performance to clear the browsing cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've seem to come across some high-quality bull crap here. No, deleting cookies from Safari will do absolutely nothing in terms of speed anywhere. The only thing it does it reset all of your login sessions for websites. That's all it does. The speed difference even in Safari will be unnoticeable.